# Частицы НЕ и НИ в предложении

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

Как правильно расставить **не** и **ни** в предложении?
*Н... Вы, н... Маша н... в чём не виноваты.*

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: ***Ни** вы, **ни** Маша **ни** в чем **не** виноваты.*

> Основная функция частицы ***ни*** — усиление отрицания. Поэтому она употребляется в предложениях с отрицательным сказуемым, т. е. сказуемым, включающим частицу ***не*** или выраженным словами *нельзя, нет*. Частица ***ни*** может быть повторяющейся (в составе союза *ни… ни*).
> Повторяющаяся частица ***ни*** (в составе союза *ни… ни*) соответствует повторяющемуся союзу ***и*** утвердительного предложения, напр.: *Они не получали ни газет, ни журналов, ни книг.* (Ср.: *Они получали и газеты, и журналы, и книги.*) *С ним не переписывались ни брат, ни сестра, ни родители.* (Ср.: *С ним переписывались и брат, и сестра, и родители.*)

*Она знала, что ни она, ни муж ее ни в чем не виноваты, и потому не боялась и думала: подержат и отпустят* (М. Н. Волконский. Черный человек).

*Строго говоря, до решения суда ни Хорошавин, ни Гайзер, ни Урлашов, ни Белых ни в чем не виновны* (из статьи).

[Частица «ни» в союзе «ни... ни»](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B8/)